# How to write mvc applications that are "hookable"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, hook

I am trying to figure out a design pattern that would allow "hooking" into an existing mvc application without re-compiling that entire application.

For example, my company currently uses classic asp for most of their large clients. Our e-commerce product is used by many of our clients, but it accesses shared scripts fo many functions so that if a bug is found we can modify a single script rather than modifying hundreds of sites.

Is there a way to replicate this ability in mvc? My understanding is that when I compile and upload a site, any changes to that site would require the site to be recompiled again. Is that true? Or, is there a way to "Hook" into the site to make changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into MEF?

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mef

As an aside what is wrong with re-compiling the assembly with the bug and dropping a dll into place?  It is exactly the same as fixing a script and dropping it in.